# Have Error : PInvokeStackImbalance with dll

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged

I'm currently working on an USB device which takes acquisition from different equipment.

I have problem with a `typedef struct` which I'm not able to reproduce in c#.

In the source code from the Dll I have this :

```
typedef struct _UF01_INFORMATIONS{
        BYTE Type[MAX_MODULE];
        BYTE Nombre_Module;
        BYTE Nb_Voies[MAX_MODULE];
        BYTE Modele[MAX_MODULE];
        char *Name[MAX_MODULE];
        char *Comments[MAX_MODULE];
        BOOL UseInterrupt;
} UF01_INFORMATIONS, *PUF01_INFORMATIONS;

MAX_MODULE equals 8 ^^
```

This is my code :

```
    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\DLL\UFDF.dll", EntryPoint = "UF01_OpenDevices", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    unsafe static extern Boolean UF01_OpenDevices(byte* devices);

    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\DLL\UFDF.dll", EntryPoint = "UF01_CloseAll", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    unsafe static extern void UF01_CloseAll();

    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SELIAtec\DLL\UFDF.dll", EntryPoint = "UF01_UD01_8Entrees", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    unsafe static extern Boolean UF01_UD01_8Entrees(byte Device, byte module, byte* data);

    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\DLL\UFDF.dll", EntryPoint = "UF01_UD01_8Entrees", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    unsafe static extern Boolean UF01_GetInfosModule(byte Device, bool Watchdog, [In, Out] _UF01_INFORMATIONS infos);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 1)]
    public struct _UF01_INFORMATIONS
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public unsafe byte[] Type;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public unsafe byte Nombre_Module;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public unsafe byte[] Nb_Voies;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public unsafe byte[] Modele;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public unsafe string[] Name;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public unsafe string[] Comments;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public unsafe bool UseInterrupt;
    }


    private unsafe void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte nb_Device;

        _UF01_INFORMATIONS m_infos = new _UF01_INFORMATIONS();
        m_infos.Type = new byte[8];
        m_infos.Nb_Voies = new byte[8];
        m_infos.Modele = new byte[8];
        m_infos.Name = new string[8];
        m_infos.Comments = new string[8];
        m_infos.Nombre_Module = 0;
        m_infos.UseInterrupt = false;


        if (UF01_OpenDevices(&nb_Device))
        {
            this.label1.Text = "Nombre de CPU's : " + nb_Device;

            UF01_GetInfosModule(nb_Device, false, m_infos); //<== Here is the ERROR

            label2.Text = "Nombre de modules : " + m_infos.Nombre_Module;
         }
    }
```

The error at the line "UF01_GetInfosModule" is : "the PInvoke managed signature is not the same that the unmanaged one"

I'm searching but cannot find why I have this Error.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. When I use the ref argument I get no error but the function UF01_GetInfosModule returns a false now...

Comment: It seems that the data cannot be written in the ref variables. I don'y know why...

Answer (score -1):

My code is now :

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form { 

    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SELIAtec\UF01\UF01.dll", EntryPoint = "UF01_OpenDevices", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    unsafe static extern Boolean UF01_OpenDevices(ref byte devices);

    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SELIAtec\UF01\UF01.dll", EntryPoint = "UF01_CloseAll", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    unsafe static extern void UF01_CloseAll();

    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SELIAtec\UF01\UF01.dll", EntryPoint = "UF01_UD01_8Entrees", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    unsafe static extern Boolean UF01_UD01_8Entrees(byte Device, byte module, ref byte data);

    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SELIAtec\UF01\UF01.dll", EntryPoint = "UF01_UD01_8Entrees", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    unsafe static extern Boolean UF01_GetInfosModule(byte Device, bool Watchdog, ref _UF01_INFORMATIONS infos);

    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SELIAtec\UF01\UF01.dll", EntryPoint = "UF01_UA01_Entrees", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    unsafe static extern Boolean UF01_UA01_Entrees(byte Device, byte Module, ref ushort[] TableData_12bit);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _UF01_INFORMATIONS
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public byte[] Type;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte Nombre_Module;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public byte[] Nb_Voies;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public byte[] Modele;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public string[] Name;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public string[] Comments;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool UseInterrupt;
    }


    private unsafe void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte nb_Device = 0;
        ushort[] data = new ushort[8]; 

        _UF01_INFORMATIONS m_infos = new _UF01_INFORMATIONS();
        m_infos.Type = new byte[8];
        m_infos.Nb_Voies = new byte[8];
        m_infos.Modele = new byte[8];
        m_infos.Name = new string[8];
        m_infos.Comments = new string[8];
        m_infos.Nombre_Module = 0;
        m_infos.UseInterrupt = false;

        if (UF01_OpenDevices(ref nb_Device))
        {
            this.label1.Text = "Nombre de CPU's : " + nb_Device;

            if (UF01_GetInfosModule(nb_Device, false, ref m_infos))
                label2.Text = "Nombre de modules : " + m_infos.Nombre_Module.ToString();

            if (UF01_UA01_Entrees(nb_Device, 1, ref data))
                label3.Text = "Donnee : " + data[0].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The first function called UF01_OpenDevices works. It returns in the ref variable the number of devices. But the other 2 functions are not working. They return false.
I don't know why...